# Exporting Illustrator AI to SVG without a white background

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a Illustrator CS5 AI file that has two shapes in it on a transparent background/artboard. However, when I save this file as a SVG file (1.1) using "Save as", the resulting SVG file has a white background.

How do I get rid of the white background in the SVG file?

The AI file can be found here:

http://hostsafe.com/temp/in.ai

The SVG file that I keep getting can be found here:

http://hostsafe.com/temp/in.svg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exported SVGs do not contain white backgrounds; it is just another view mode (hidden transparency grid). To show the *Transparency Grid*, again, go to **View -> Show Transparency Grid** or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: `Shift` + `CMD` + `D` for mac. Still works like a charm! thanks @emax